# Ajax request and my Symfony 1.4 Response : Contents doesn't match

Tags: php, jquery, symfony-1.4

I'm using jQuery for my ajax request and Symfony 1.4 PHP in server side.

My problem is in the title.

How to reproduce :

I have a footer (in all my pages) to display Tweets of my web site who have a kind of "keep alive call" to get last Tweets every 7s.

```
function loadNotyTweets(tweetCount) {

    var jqXhr = $.ajax({
        'url':'<?php echo url_for(array('module' => 'footer', 'action' => 'getLastApiTweets')) ?>',
        'type':'GET',
        'async':true,
        'dataType':'json',
        'cache': false
    }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (data != null) {
            var j = 0;
            for (var i in data) {
                var text = formatNoty(data[i]['text'], data[i]['user']['screen_name'], data[i]['user']['name'], data[i]['user']['profile_image_url_https'], data[i]['created_at']),
                    hashTweet = calcMD5(text);

                if (!$.cookie(hashTweet) || $.cookie(hashTweet) != 'close') {
                    // Display a noty containing my tweet
                    generateNoty(text);
                }
                j++;
                if (j == tweetCount) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

And in server side :

```
function executeGetLastApiTweets(sfWebRequest $request) {
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

            // Get tweet using Twitter API
            $tweets = $this->getApiTweets($request);

            $lastTweet = '';
            if (isset($tweets[0]) && isset($tweets[0]['text'])) {
                $lastTweet = md5($tweets[0]['text']);
            }

            if ($this->isLastTweet($lastTweet)) {
                return $this->renderText(json_encode($this->getTweetsUI($tweets)));
            }

        }
        return sfView::NONE;
    }
```

Now, when I click on my web site on a link (just after my loadTweets() is calling) I get the response of this Ajax call instead of the response of the link i click.

I have no idea of what appenning here...

For info :

I've my Apache deflate compression active. I think it could come from this.

There is, my Apache Conf.

```
    # MOD_DEFLATE COMPRESSION
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/plain text/xml application/x-javascript application/x-httpd-php
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

    # BEGIN Expire headers
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
     ExpiresActive On
     ExpiresDefault "access plus 7200 seconds"
     ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 days"
     ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 days"
     ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 days"
     ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 days"
     AddType image/x-icon .ico
     ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 7 days"
     ExpiresByType image/icon "access plus 7 days"
     ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 7 days "
     ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 7 days"
     ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 7 days"
     ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 7200 seconds"
     ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 7200 seconds"
     ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 7 days"
     ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 7 days"
     ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 days"
    </IfModule>
    # END Expire headers
# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 <FilesMatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|gz|ttf)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
 </FilesMatch>
 <FilesMatch "\\.(css)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
 </FilesMatch>
 <FilesMatch "\\.(js)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
 </FilesMatch>
 <filesMatch "\\.(html|htm)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, public"
 </filesMatch>
 # Disable caching for scripts and other dynamic files
 <FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
   Header unset Cache-Control
 </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers

# KILL THEM ETAGS
Header unset ETag
FileETag none
```

Comment: Have you tried to change some Apache settings? It looks like a problem with Apache. I don't think there is any possibility PHP or Symfony could mess with two different requests in such way. Or maybe it's a problem with your JS and links. Have you checked if when you click on a link the request is made to the proper URL?

Comment: It can't come from my JS. My links are HTML links without any "on-click" jQuery Events Binded. I think that it's can come from my Apache Settings, but it's weird ! How could it be ? What can be wrong with my apache config ?

Comment: But have you checked that? Open Firebug, Fiddler, or anything like that. You can inspect on each request you make from the browser. Yuo can see what URL is called and what you get as a response. When you're sure you're calling the right page and get the wrong response you can think what is wrong with the Apache.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I've already try that. My "Keep alive" JS call the good request and have good response but, when I click on my link (html link, no JS is call) I have a redirection to the good URL (URL of my link) but it's show the previous response from my keep alive JS call.

Comment: By "shows the previous response" you mean the server returns this response? 
Try fiddling with the Apache settings - disabling modules one by one, maybe you'll find what it is.

Comment: Yeah, the response is the server response. Instead-of shows the link URL response, it Shows the response of my previous Ajax Call (the keep alive call). So typically, it's shows the Tweets in JSON Formated. I will try to do what you said, and i'll comme back here to post my results ;-).

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that when you click on *any* link on your site, you get the json response back? Can you please explain the problem a bit better? Perhaps showing us the HTML that your page is producing will help. I'm guessing your anchor tag is linking to the wrong route?

Answer (score 2):

You declared your ajax variable as:

```
var jqXhr = $.ajax({
```

Then you reference your variable as:

```
}).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
```

Correct me if I'm wrong,
javascript/jquery variables are case-sensitive.

Comment: Yeah, it's case sensitive, but the first jqXhr is not the same object than the jqXHR. Well, if i want, i can remove the jqXHR parameter from the done function. I doesn't use it.